# How to run weston-launch by default

Tags: 16.04, xorg, wayland, weston

How to run `weston-launch` by default instead of *Unity* on *Ubuntu* 16.04?

I want to run my application at startup (like in `~/.config/upstart/*.conf`) in `wayland` environment. Is it feasible at the moment?

I need a most minimalistic window manager possible. I don't need gestures and other high-level features, just one full-screen window plus possibility to run `weston-terminal` to perform debug/tweaking actions.

Comment: How did you install wayland ? If from the ppa - there may be a package, gnome-session-wayland `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-wayland` This will add "Gnome on Wayland" to GDM . If there is no such package, you would have to install GDM and gnome-shell (lightdm apparently will not launch weston ?) . You would then autologin. If all that is too much, there is an elegant solution on the Arch forums you may be able to adapt : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=102366

Comment: The 2 problems you face are to start X and auto login at boot without light/gdm or slim. Other links https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243674 and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Automatic_login_into_Xorg_without_display_manager

Answer (score 1):

you may have to disable lightdm or gdm, then with logind alone `weston` would start it from `tty`

weston does not have an autostart feature although you may find an outdated patch online

you could add [launcher]s to the panel for your applications though

anything else would be started from your terminal emulator

[weston.ini man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man5/weston.ini.5.html)